# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::render()

Tags: pagination, laravel-5

I am experience this error when I try to paginate a blog post using laravel 5
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::render()
Kindly assist on this issue

Comment: Post the code that causes the error if you want help

Comment: <div class="pagination-center">

                            {{ $listing->business->posts->render() }}
                        </div>

Comment: you dont have a paginator, that is a collection. you can update your original question with additional information when requested.

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple , you just need to pass collection of data from controller to view with `paginate(number)` for example in my project i pass collection of brand data with this line of code  `$brands = Brand::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$category.'%')->latest()->paginate(5);` and now view can render each 5 object.